# Can we create an object of a class (super or sub class) which cannot invoke any methods from the class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, reference

This question was asked to one of my friend in an interview.

> Assume that there is a class called
> **A** which is a super class and a sub class called **B** . Class **A** has a method called **blah()** which is also overridden in the subclass **B** . So create a  object in such a way that object created cannot invoke any of the methods from both class(can use both upcasting and downcasting).Is this possible in java or not. If possible construct the object.

So I tried this but I'm getting only ClassCast Exception at runtime.
So the above mentioned question is possible or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible in Java. We can always make methods accessible through [reflection (external link to baeldung.com)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection).

Comment: @Turing is the above mentioned question is possible without reflection?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). --- Even without reflection, we could use bytecode manipulation.

Comment: If we assume that A and B are in package `x` and methods added/overridden are package-private (without any visibility modifier) then in other packages we can crate instance of A and B (assuming classes are public and have public constructors) and we will not be able to access package-private methods (without reflection).

Comment: @Turing Comments are meant only for discursion so only I asked it.

Comment: The interview question is extremely poor. The English is unclear, and the constraints are not sufficiently specified.

Comment: `C c = new C()` seems to satisfy the question.  I've (1) created an object, and (2) `c` cannot access `A` or `B` methods by upcasting or downcasting.  (There are details of what A and B have to look like, but you get the gist).  I assume reflection to be outlawed because of the wording around upcast/downcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in java,

```
static class A{
    public void printF(){

        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
static class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void printF(){

        System.out.println("b");
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    A obj1 = new A();
    obj1.printF();
    B obj2 = new B();
    obj2.printF();

    A obj3 = new B();
    obj3.printF();

    // this will throw error
    B obj4 = (A)new B();
    B obj5 = new A();
}
```

So we can expect the outputs as below,

1. `obj1.printF()` will print `a` because it is created using the **class A**
2. `obj2.printF()` will print `b` because it is created using the **class B** and **class A** is the superclass of **class B** because **class B is inheriting the class A** and **class B is overriding the method in class A**
3. `obj3.printF()` will print `b` because it is created using **class B** and due to **class B is overriding class A** `printF()` method.And this is using upcasting in java
   *(upcasting - Upcasting is the typecasting of a child object to a parent)*
4. `B obj4 = (A)new B()` or `B obj5 = new A();` is not possible in java this is trying to downcast an object implicitly,and this will throw the `ClassCastException`
   *(ClassCastException -Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.)*

The approach in java for downcasting is to use `instanceOf()` method. It is downcasting explicitly.

```
A obj3 = new B();
if(obj3 instanceof B){
  B obj5 = (B)obj3;
  obj5.printF();
}
```

*(Downcasting-downcasting means the typecasting of a parent object to a child object. Downcasting cannot be implicit.)*